# Blackberry Clickable BitmapField

Tags: blackberry, bitmapfield

I want to create a Custom BitmapField for putting Icons on my Menu Screen. I want them to be Clicked. I also want to give the X and Y coordinates of the icon as parameter to the Custom BitmapField. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomMenuButtonField extends Field{
Bitmap normal,focused;
public CustomMenuButtonField(String bitmap1, String bitmap2) {

    normal = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(bitmap1);
    focused = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(bitmap2);

}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(width, height); // Set them according to your design  
}

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{
    fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}

public boolean isFocusable() {
    return true;
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

    if(isFocus())
    {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, focused, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, width, height, normal, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

}

If you want to give coordinates as parameters , add them. Height and width is up to you..