# Calling a Bitmap Class in Java

Tags: java, blackberry, graphics, bitmap

I found this post on the site:

[Blackberry Clickable BitmapField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722875/blackberry-clickable-bitmapfield)

explaining a class where you can draw a clickable bitmap. This is exactly what I want to do but the issue for me is that I'm quite new to Java and I don't know how to properly call this statement. What are the commands to create this bitmap? So far all I have is:

```
CustomMenuButtonField buttonInstance = new CustomMenuButtonField("img1.png", "img2.png");
```

aside from that I don't know how to make the drawing appear. If I try:

```
buttonInstance.paint(graphics);
```

I need to declare graphics which I am not sure how to do. I've checked the API but its still a bit confusing to me. Also where should these call statements be used? In the userInterface constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create your custom button field, you just need to add it to your screen:

```
add(buttonInstance);
```

It will then be displayed by the framework automatically. For more info, see the Getting Started Guide for the SDK version you are using in the [Development Guides](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Java%20Development%20Guides%20and%20API%20Reference).

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot and the image is appearing. A weird thing that is happening is that the second image remains on the display after I click it, even after I exit and enter the app again. If I want to have the image change back to the original once one opens and exits or resets how would I do this?

Comment: @user1152440 - That would depend on your code. I suggest that you ask a new question and post more info about what you're trying to do and what the problem is.